# Is it possible that $x\in \overline{A\cap B}$ for $x\in A$ \ $B$ - open

Tags: general-topology

Is the following possible:

> For a Hausdorff space (don't know if that's needed), let $x\in A$ \ $B$ for $A,B\subseteq_{op}X$. Is it possible that $x\in\overline{A\cap B}$?

What about if $X$ is extremally disconnected (that is, the closure of each open set is open)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: When (if at all) is it possible that $cl(A \cap B)$ contains a point outside $B$?

Comment: It is equivalent to proving that cl$(A\cap B) \subseteq$ cl$(A)\cap B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. In general, whenever $(A \cap B)$ is dense in some neighbourhood of a point in $A \setminus B$, $cl(A \cap B)$ wll contain that point.

Suppose $A = X = [0,1]$. Let $\{q_n\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$. For some $\epsilon < 1$, let $B_{2^{-n}\epsilon}(q_n)$ be the open ball of diameter $2^{-n}\epsilon$ around $q_n$, and let $B = \bigcup_{n}B_{2^{-n}\epsilon}(q_n)$.

$B$ is open and dense in $A$, so $cl(B) = A$. And the Lebesgue measure of $B$, $\mu(B) \leq \sum_{n \geq 1}2^{-n}\epsilon = \epsilon < 1 = \mu(A)$, so $B$ is a proper subset of $A$, i.e., $A \setminus B$ is non-empty.

This shows that $A \cap B = B$, but $B$ is dense in $A$ so $cl(A \cap B) = A$.